# How to generate a point distance matrix using shortest network distance?

Tags: distance, network

My problem is as follows.

To start with, I have the following spatial datasets:

- A road network;
- 13,000 odd point locations representing populated localities (ie places where people live);
- Service (point) locations (2000+) representing the location of a specific human service;

For each populated locality (origins), I need to find the network distance to the 5 nearest service locations (destinations), and record those 5 distance measures against the originating populated locality.

Software resources available to me include ArcMap (ArcView licence only), Manifold (with Business Tools extension), Quantum GIS, GvSIG.

Any help or suggestions welcome.

Comment: Given QGIS, do you have access to GRASS? If you you could maybe take a look at [v.net.allpairs](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/html70_user/v.net.allpairs.html) which might help. Probably take a _while_ to process given the number of points though...

Comment: I believe the [CrimeStat](http://www.icpsr.umich.edu/CrimeStat/) program has the capabilities to do this as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your could use [pgRouting](http://www.pgrouting.org/) with [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/).

[This page](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/) from [underdark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/187)'s website explains how to do.

Good luck !